# Post Service call with Multiple records

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I would like to know how to post multiple records to SAP using "BatchRequestBuilder" along with ChangeSet .I am using a custom odata service call(ODataCreateRequestBuilder),not using the VDM model.  I did'nt get any blog or documentation to start with.

Can you please help me in this regard.

Updated:
Below is what I am trying to post to SAP
[{"purchaseSchAgrmntNo":"","customerMaterialNumber":"","plant":"","vendorNo":""},{"purchaseSchAgrmntNo":"","customerMaterialNumber":"","plant":"","vendorNo":""}]

SAP SDK version : 3.9.0

I have added below code with only one CreateRequest.

ChangeSet changeSet = new ChangeSetBuilder().addCreateRequest(               ODataCreateRequestBuilder.withEntity(sapConfig.getServiceUrlRepriceList(),
                        sapConfig.getEntityRepriceList())
                        .withBodyAsMap(responseBody)
                        .build()).build();

BatchResult batchResult =  BatchRequestBuilder.withService("URL?").addChangeSet(changeSet).build().execute(httpClient);

Can you let me know if this is correct.Also let me know what I have to pass in the service.Is it service URL?

Thanks,
Arun Pai

Comment: Yes as far as I can see the above should work. And yes you pass in the service URL path, e.g. /sap/abc/MY_API. However, unless you don't know the service you want to query at compile time, I recommend that you leverage the generator to generate this code so that you can use the VDM instead which simplifies this.

Comment: Did that clarify things for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so others see it too.

Answer (score 1):

The `BatchRequestBuilder` is actually not directly part of the SAP Cloud SDK but a dependency that the SDK internally uses to execute batch requests. That is why on the SDK level there is no documentation on how to use it.

Roughly, a batch request comprises of multiple change sets which in turn group together multiple operations. The `ChangeSetBuilder` allows you to build up change sets which you can then pass to a `BatchRequestBuilder`.

So if you want to run create requests in batch mode you would want to leverage `public ChangeSetBuilder addCreateRequest(ODataCreateRequest oDataCreateRequest)`.

You can take a look at how the SAP Cloud SDK uses these classes to build up batch requests to get an idea how it works in detail. As a starting point look towards `BatchFluentHelperBasic`. However, unless you don't know the service you want to query at compile time, I recommend that you leverage the generator to generate this code so that you can use the VDM instead which simplifies this.

If you extend your question to hold more specific information on what you actually want to achieve I can expand my answer to give a more concrete example. Also please include the SDK version you are using.

Comment: Thanks Mat for the reply. I have updated the requirement and sdk version.